# Issue with concatenation using `##` operator

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, preprocessor-directive

I am concatenating two numbers using the `##` operator. The code gives error when I use variables but works fine when I give direct input.

Gives an error.

> [Error] 'xy' undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define join(a, b)  a##b ; 

int main()
{
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
int res ;
res = join(x, y);
printf("%d",res) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

Works Fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define join(a, b)  a##b ; 

int main()
{
int res ;
res = join(99, 10);
printf("%d",res) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, preprocessor MACROS are textual substitution, so in case when you're using variables, after preprocessing your code looks like

```
res = xy;
```

now this `xy` is an undefined identifier in your code.

OTOH, when you're passing integer constants, you code looks like

```
res = 9910;
```

which is perfectly valid.

To elaborate on the working of the `##` operator, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.10.3.3 (*emphasis mine*)

> in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by **the corresponding argument’s preprocessing token sequence**; [...]

Answer (score 2):

The `##` preprocessing operator performs token pasting. And tokens are checked at Compile time.

What do you think this `res = join(x, y);` is supposed to mean?

```
res = xy;
```

The `C` compiler should give a compilation error.

This `res = join(99, 10);` means

```
res = 9910;
```

Which is valid in C syntax. Also remember that Macros are not type-safe so use casts like this:

```
res = (int) join(99, 10);
```

Your code would be valid if you had `xy` declared before something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define join(a, b)  a##b ; 

int main()
{
    int xy = 100;
    int res ;
    res = (int) join(x, y);
    printf("%d",res) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```